# VBA to open all web-links in a single row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an Excel file with 2 worksheets.

- `Sheet1` contains a drop down created in cell D3 containing a list of countries and a 'launch' button.
- `Sheet2` contains "Country Names" in Column A and their respective web-links in Column B, C, D, and so on. For example, for Country Name as Australia in A1, the respective web-links are in B1, C1, D1, and so on.

On clicking on the launch button, it should open all the links of that country available in a row. How can I achieve that in Excel VBA?

Sample sheet can be viewed at:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17PqwEvrvO4JCaK5PNzK_D-JQfW3aj4KzZ2R40QBp2V8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below by linking your button to the macro `LaunchWebPages`.

The method to launch the webpage is using the `Shell` command which runs the exe and passes in the link as a parameter.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const BROWSER_EXE = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

Public Sub LaunchWebpages()

    Dim wsOptions As Worksheet
    Dim rngOption As Range
    Dim wsLinks As Worksheet
    Dim rngCountry As Range
    Dim lngCounter As Long, lngLinkCount As Long
    Dim rngLink As Range
    Dim strLink As String

    'get input
    Set wsOptions = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngOption = wsOptions.Range("D3")

    'find key on other sheet
    Set wsLinks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngCountry = wsLinks.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=rngOption.Text)

    'quit if no match
    If rngCountry Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No match found for " & rngOption.Text
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'open links
    lngLinkCount = rngCountry.End(xlToRight).Column
    For lngCounter = 2 To lngLinkCount
        Set rngLink = wsLinks.Cells(rngCountry.Row, lngCounter)
        strLink = rngLink.Text
        Shell BROWSER_EXE & " " & strLink, vbNormalNoFocus
    Next lngCounter

End Sub
```

I've named `iexplore.exe` so this macro will use Internet Explorer for the web-browser. You might prefer to change this to Chrome or something else.